# Start node server on machine startup

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-16.04, upstart

I was trying to start node.js server on startup of the machine (ubuntu 16.04) with upstart by using the the following code in nodeserv.conf file:

```
#!upstart
description "Node.js server"
author "Sushant Kumar"

start on started mountall
stop on shutdown

respawn
respawn limit 99 5

script
    export APP_HOME = "/home/ubuntu/chatbot_server"
    export HOME = "/home/ubuntu"
    cd $APP_HOME
    exec sudo -u ubuntu /usr/local/nodejs/bin/node $HOME/chatbot_server/server.js >> /var/log/chatbotserv.log 2>&1
end script

post-start script
    echo "Node Started"
end script
```

, but I run the command

```
# start nodeserv
```

I get the followig error: `>>start: Job failed to start`.
Can anyone help me please where I am going wrong?

Edit: This server is hosted on AWS EC2 instance (if that helps, I don't think it's relevant, but just in case).

Comment: Don't know about pm2, but i used forever-service but it could not succeed. I dont want to use any more modules/packages, just want to know why this script isn't working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by running your app as a service. You can use [forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever) to ensure that a given script runs continuously. First of all you need to install forever. Then go to your project directory and install forever-monitor. Now you can start your app.

```
npm install forever -g
cd /path/to/your/project
npm install forever-monitor
forever start app.js
```

Now you need to use [forever-service](https://github.com/zapty/forever-service) to build your node script as a service.Firstly, install forever-service and then install your app as a service.

```
npm install -g forever-service
forever-service install test
```

If you want to work on your script, you can replace this code in your script.

```
export HOME="/root"
exec /usr/local/nodejs/bin/node /home/ubuntu/chatbot_server/server.js >> /var/log/node.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 4):

Have a look on [PM2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-3-%E2%80%94-installing-pm2).

PM2 is a really powerful Node.js process manager.

After install your app, you can easily set it on startup with:

```
sudo systemctl start pm2-yourusername
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way to start npm automatically without pm2 and on an older system, with rc.d/init.d scripts (Slackware 14 in my example):

1. We're gonna use "--prefix". When you start your node manually you're probably first moving to the folder with it and starting it from there. With "prefix" you can point to that folder directly.
2. Let's create our startup script. In my case (Slackware 14) it's located in /etc/rc.d:

   touch /etc/rc.d/rc.npm-somenodestartup
   chmod +x /etc/rc.d/rc.npm-somenodestartup
   vim /etc/rc.d/rc.npm-somenodestartup

paste the following:

```
#!/bin/sh

case "$1" in
'start')
sleep 30
npm start --prefix /home/somefolder/www/somenode & ;;
# 'stop')
# 'restart')
*)
esac
```

- note "sleep 30" (seconds) - we want our node to start last, after complete system startup. 30s should be enough.
- "&" makes the command run in the background
- "--prefix" is of course our node's location.
- also note stop and restart options - I left them deliberately as an example.

At this point executing:

```
/etc/rc.d/rc.npm-somenodestartup
```

should start your node.

3. And for starting it automatically: just edit /etc/rc.d/rc.local:

   vim /etc/rc.d/rc.local

paste:

```
if [ -x /etc/rc.d/rc.npm-somenodestartup ]; then
        /etc/rc.d/rc.npm-somenodestartup start
fi
```

4. Reboot the system - your node should be up and running.

Have fun!